# Why after split line into an array, the code after for-loop doesn't work?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, output

In this cycle, the string within an arraylist is divided, and each word is inserted into an array. I only need the date that is in second position to compare it with a date that I pass. If it is not present, the entire string is deleted from the arraylist.

For this reason I use an iterator. Everything works but the code after the for loop doesn't work. Eliminating the insertion of words in the array works everything. I used the same method elsewhere and it works without problems, I don't understand.

```
CreateMap(ArrayList<String> eventi,String data) throws ParseException {


    list_eventi = eventi;
    intervallo = data;

    String [] periodo;
    String[] arrayData;

    periodo = intervallo.split("-");
    String data_in = periodo[0];
    String data_fin = periodo[1];

    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy");

    Date dateIn = format.parse(data_in);
    Date dateFin = format.parse(data_fin);


    String[] line;

    for (Iterator<String> iter = eventi.listIterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
        String a = iter.next();
        line = a.split(" ");  //this is the problem// 
        String d = line[2];
        Date dateImport = format.parse(d);

        if(!dateImport.before(dateIn) && !dateImport.after(dateFin)) {
            //date che sono nell'intervallo
            // date between 
            System.out.println(d);
        } else{
            System.out.println("dati da eliminare " + a);
            //iter.remove();

        }

    }
------------------------------ after this line the code doesn't execute

    System.out.println("dati rimanenti");
    System.out.println(list_eventi.toString());

    //Map_for_login(eventi);
    //Map_for_all(eventi);
```

There is no error message after executing the code, but after the for loop there are other methods and various system.out but they don't work

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variable names and method names are written in camelCase.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't use the obsolete `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` classes; use the new Java Date and Time API, available in the `java.time` package.

Answer (score 0):

Since your variable `eventi` is an `ArrayList` you can just use the `.forEach()` method.

Fix:

```
    List<String> resEventi = new ArrayList(); // the resulting eventi arrayList with only the correct values
    eventi.forEach( a -> {
        line = a.split(" ");
        String d = line[2];
        Date dateImport = format.parse(d);

        if(!dateImport.before(dateIn) && !dateImport.after(dateFin)) {
            //date che sono nell'intervallo
            // date between 
            resEventi.add(a);
            System.out.println(d);
        } else{
            System.out.println("dati da eliminare " + a);
        }
    });
```

This should work given you pass in proper data (there may be an exception raised by `format.parse(d)`).

Comment: Nono, the data is correct, because my string is format "IN LOGIN 09042019 ac11b 45.463,9.188 A" then the date is in second position (date format ddmmyyyy). Sorry I expressed myself badly.

Comment: Ok, i find the problem. It wasn't on the code, but it was on the file.txt that I read. Thank you for support